# How to do nullable One-to-Many relationships in SQLAlchemy 2.0 and with type annotations?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pytest, mypy, python-3.10

I am working on a Python project which is using SQLAlchemy 2.0. Trying to improve my coding style, I am currently adding type annotations to my code. I follow the SQLAlchemy 2.0 documentation about [Basic Relationship Patterns](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/basic_relationships.html#basic-relationship-patterns), which uses `Mapped` and `mapped_column()` to type annotate a column type. This works as expected, including [Nullable Many-to-One](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/basic_relationships.html#nullable-many-to-one) relationships. However, I get the following error message, when I try to execute code that refers to a **Nullable One-to-Many** relationship:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/sfuehr/GitHubRepositories/kluw-vault/src/components/forms.py", line 440, in save_entry
    new_project = Project(id=project_id, name=self.name_var.get())
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<string>", line 4, in __init__
  File "/home/sfuehr/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/time-journal-hdIz5qQc-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 566, in _initialize_instance
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "/home/sfuehr/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/time-journal-hdIz5qQc-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 147, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "/home/sfuehr/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/time-journal-hdIz5qQc-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 564, in _initialize_instance
    manager.original_init(*mixed[1:], **kwargs)
  File "<string>", line 8, in __init__
  File "/home/sfuehr/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/time-journal-hdIz5qQc-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 536, in __set__
    self.impl.set(
  File "/home/sfuehr/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/time-journal-hdIz5qQc-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 1944, in set
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: Incompatible collection type: None is not list-like
```

The error occurs, when I try to create a new project with only an ID and a name. I defined the relationship `activities` with `default=None`, so the program tries to insert a `None` value there, but for some reason the type annotation `Mapped[List["Activity"] | None]` doesn't seem to work as I expect it to.

Here is my project class:

```
# project.py

class Project(MappedAsDataclass, Base):
    __tablename__ = "projects"
    # Using mapped_column for additional column configurations
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    # Using only Mapped
    name: Mapped[str]
    # Nullable column with simple string
    description: Mapped[str | None] = mapped_column(default=None)
    # Nullable Many-to-One relationship column
    project_category_id: Mapped[int | None] = mapped_column(
        Integer, ForeignKey("project_categories.id"), default=None
    )
    project_category: Mapped[ProjectCategory | None] = relationship(
        "ProjectCategory", default=None
    )
    # Not working: One-to-Many relationship
    activities: Mapped[List["Activity"] | None] = relationship(
        back_populates="project",
        default=None,
    )
```

My model for `Activity` looks as follows:

```
class Activity(Base):
    __tablename__ = "activities"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String)
    description: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String)
    project_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, ForeignKey("projects.id"))
    project: Mapped["Project"] = relationship("Project", back_populates="activities")

    def __init__(self, id: int, name: str) -> None:
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
```

Do you have any suggestions for where the error could come from? Is my type annotation false? Is it not possible to define a nullable Many-to-One relationship? How can I make the code above runnable?

Any help is very much appreciated :)

PS: I tagged the post as Python 3.10, as I use `Type | None` instead of `Optional[Type]`, which is only [supported since that version](https://peps.python.org/pep-0604/).

Comment: I can't test it right now, but wouldn't the many side of the relationship just be an empty list (instead of None)?